# Decrease in wages

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Due to a bad economical situation wages of the employees will be
>   decreased by 4 % or 150 dollars.
>
> For Laura both choices lead to the same situation. Calculate Laura's
>   initial salary ?
>
> For Tony it is better to decrease his salary by 150 dollars because in
>   that way he will get 35 dollars more. Calculate Tony's initial salary ?

From where to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about modeling the choices algebraically?
$$
S_L (100\% - 4\%) = S_L - 150 \\
S_T - 150 = S_T (100\% - 4\%) + 35
$$

Comment: You just had to answer, eh?  So I guess my comment to the asker is now rendered meaningless. Too bad.

Comment: Not fully, though.

Comment: I was not looking for a full answer. However your answer helped me to understand and solve it thanks mvw  :) .